# Help with Rotational Vector Matrix problem

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, vectors, contest-math

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be two by two matrix [sqrt(3)/2, -1/2; 1/2, sqrt(3)/2]. Then what is
$\mathbf{A}^{2018} \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}?$

I am stuck and cannot think of a method of simplifying.

I know that A * \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} is equal to (sqrt(3)-1;sqrt(3)+1). I tried to do A^2017(A*\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}) but it doesn't lead me anywhere.

Comment: This isn't how I would solve it, but if nothing better, try computing some of the first powers of $A$ and hope for some regularity to come about (hint: it does), then use it to your advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A=\pmatrix{\sqrt3/2 & -1/2\\1/2 & \sqrt3/2\\}=
\pmatrix{\cos\pi/6 & -\sin\pi/6\\\sin\pi/6 & \cos\pi/6 \\}
$$
is a rotation matrix, corresponding to an angle of $30°$. Hence $A^6=-1$ and $A^{2018}=A^2$.